# Am I getting the right fps?

Tags: java, swing

So I am for the first time using swing only to make a pong clone. I've copied a very simple gameloop from the internet and just adapted it for swing, but I'm getting an absurd number for fps... I don't know if it's right, can anyone help me?

```
  public void run() {
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    long secondsTimer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long nowTime;
    double ns = 1000000000 / 60;
    double delta = 0;
    int updates = 0;
    int fps = 0;
    while (!quit) {
      nowTime = System.nanoTime();
      delta += (nowTime - lastTime) / ns;
      lastTime = nowTime;
      while (delta >= 1) {
        --delta;
        update();
        ++updates;
      }
      repaint();
      ++fps;
      if (System.currentTimeMillis() - secondsTimer >= 1000) {
        secondsTimer += 1000;
        window.setTitle(GAME_TITLE + " | UPDATES: " + updates + " FPS: " + fps);
        updates = 0;
        fps = 0;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: *"I've copied a very simple gameloop from the internet and just adapted it for swing,"* For a Swing based animation, use the Swing `Timer`. Doing so ensures that GUI elements are changed on the EDT.

Comment: `but I'm getting an absurd number for fps` so what is the fps you are getting?

Comment: @user3437460 I'm getting like 200000 fps, but when I used java awt the fps stick around 2000...